# Javascript function to click on a button when user is idle for 10sec

Tags: javascript, web, timer

I need to embed a javascript function that automatically clicks on a button on my website when the user didn't click on any button for 10 seconds, is it possible to do ? If so, how would you do it ?

Thank you a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

write setTimeOut function and give exact same function as the button did

```
  setTimeout(() => {() => {button func}}, 10000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Sorry but I am a simple CSS/HTML front end developper and so I don't know how I could use your code to make a full function, would it be possible for you to write the full code ? I'd like to get the element by ID ('.button') and click on it when the user didn't click anywhere on the website for 10seconds. Sorry if it's too much asked for a free help but my javascript skills are really low and I cannot pay a javascript developer for the moment

Comment: Instead of simulating a click on the button, you should directly run the function that runs when you click the button. Simulating a click is just running this function with extra steps. That's what this answer is about. Use `setTimeout( onButtonClicked, 10000)`, with `onButtonClicked()` being the function that is executed on click.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I don't know javascript syntax, I just know where I should put it and how to get elements by id, so would it be possible for you to write the full code starting from <script> and ending with </script> ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, I merged your codes with others I found on the web and here is what I came up with, it works perfectly! Here is the code if someone ever needs it :

```
<script>
var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 10; //seconds
var _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
document.onclick = function() {
_idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};
document.onmousemove = function() {
_idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};
document.onkeypress = function() {
_idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};
window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);

function CheckIdleTime() {
_idleSecondsCounter++;
var oPanel = document.getElementById("SecondsUntilExpire");
if (oPanel)
    oPanel.innerHTML = (IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter) + "";
if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
    document.getElementById('button').click();
  
}
}

</script>
```